# CakePHP - How to reassign Paginator parameter

Tags: cakephp, pagination

I'm facing a problem that I do not understand.

In my controller:

```
$this->paginate = $a;
$list1 = $this->paginate('Model');
$this->paginate = $b;
$list2 = $this->paginate('Model');
```

My question is, why $list2 is exactly the same as $list1 while I already changed $this->paginate after getting $list1? And, how to make those code work so that I can get $list1 and $list2 according to $a and $b?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Just a hunch:
What happens, when you do the following:

```
$this->paginate = $a;
$list1 = $this->paginate('Model');
$this->paginate = array();
$this->paginate = $b;
$list2 = $this->paginate('Model');
```

Are the values of $a and $b distinct?

Comment: The result is the same when I add $this->paginate = array(); like your comment.

$a and $b are different. I also debug $this->paginate after assigned and they are different too, but $list1 and $list2 are still the same.

Comment: Can you share more data (in brief) on what's in $a and $b?